# Strange navigation bar animation when transitioning to a child UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uicontainerview, childviewcontroller

I have created a small project to replicate this problem.

The only file is this one...

### Brief bit of code

```
class RootViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        showBlue()
    }

    @objc func showBlue() {
        let vc = UIViewController()
        vc.view.backgroundColor = .blue

        let nvc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)

        vc.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(showGreen))

        transition(to: nvc)
    }

    @objc func showGreen() {
        let vc = UIViewController()
        vc.view.backgroundColor = .green

        let nvc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)

        vc.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(showBlue))

        transition(to: nvc)
    }

    func transition(to toVC: UIViewController) {
        if let fromVC = children.first {
            transitionWithAnimation(fromVC: fromVC, toVC: toVC)
        } else {
            addWithoutAnimation(child: toVC)
        }
    }

    func addWithoutAnimation(child toVC: UIViewController) {
        addChild(toVC)
        view.addSubview(toVC.view)
        toVC.view.frame = view.bounds
        toVC.didMove(toParent: self)
    }

    func transitionWithAnimation(fromVC: UIViewController, toVC: UIViewController) {
        addChild(toVC)
        toVC.view.frame = view.bounds

        fromVC.willMove(toParent: nil)

        transition(
            from: fromVC,
            to: toVC,
            duration: 1.0,
            options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
            animations: nil) { _ in
                fromVC.removeFromParent()
                toVC.didMove(toParent: self)
        }
    }
}
```

### Explaining the code

The RootViewController first does `showBlue`. This adds a child `UINavigationController` with a `rootViewController` with a blue background. The blue view controller has a `Done` button that then targets `showGreen`.

`showGreen` transitions to a `UINavigationController` with a green background and a `Done` button that targets `showBlue`.

### What I expected

What I expected (and what I want to happen) is for the navigation bar to cross dissolve in place without resizing.

### Animation of the problem

The problem is that during the animated transition the navigation bar has a strange animation to it. Which you can see here...

[image]

### Apple documentation around this

All the code is followed exactly from the Apple documentation about adding child view controllers to a custom container view controller... https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html

### Things I tried

I have also tried by using AutoLayout constraints rather than setting the view's frame directly but this didn't change anything.

I've tried running `view.setNeedsLayout` and then `view.layoutIfNeeded()` on the new view controller's `view` but that doesn't seem to have fixed it either.

### No strange animation if child is not UINavigationController

The really odd thing is that if you use any other type of view controller (other than `UINavigationController`) then this animation glitch doesn't happen. For example: If one of the view controllers is a `UITabBarController` then the tabs do not have this odd animation. Even stranger, if the tab contains a `UINavigationController` then it doesn't have this animation either. It's literally just if the direct child is a `UINavigationController`.

Has anyone experienced this before? And did you manage to stop the strange animation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you place the transition code within a `CATransaction` and use the `kCATransactionDisableActions` key to turn off implicit actions it will resolve the issue:

```
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setValue(kCFBooleanTrue, forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions)
        
    transition(
        from: fromVC,
        to: toVC,
        duration: 1.0,
        options: [.transitionCrossDissolve],
        animations: nil) { _ in
            fromVC.removeFromParent()
            toVC.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
        
    CATransaction.commit()
```